# How to enable the 'Locals' tab in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've tried running the debugger in VS. I see the error list, but I could not find the local tab to tell me what is going on inside the code. Would someone please tell me how to enable the tab?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the hotkey chord: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd>

Or, while running your program, select on the toolbar: `Debug > Windows > Locals`